# Nested SELECT vs INNER JOIN

Tags: python, sql, django

I've got this `model.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    omei = models.FloatField(max_length=16)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class LatLong(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    long = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.lat)+str(" ")+str(self.long)
```

Given three inputs, `time1`, `time2`, `omei`, I want a set of `LatLongs` that are between `time1` and `time2` which are referenced to a vehicle with the given `omei`.

From what I know, there are two ways of doing this: using a nested `SELECT`, or using `INNER JOIN`.

What are the tradeoffs of these approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
latlongs = LatLong.objects.filter(date__gte=time1, date__lte=time2, vehicle__omei=omei)
```